# How to determine whether a drive is network mounted?

Tags: windows, winapi

I am searching for all drives and their contents. I don't want to search network drives. How can I determine if a given drive is network mounted? What I would want further is to get similar information one gets using NET USE command?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want the [GetDriveType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364939.aspx) function.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you would like to add remove drives or check status, check this article out:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/173011

That's using the win32 api.